# Shared HealthKit integration in Xcode for iOS and WatchOS

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos, info.plist

maybe you can help me with the following topic:

I have developed an iOS app with HealthKit integration. All access rights to HealthKit are set up in the info.plist file.

[image: info.plist in the iOS part of my project]

I wanted to integrate also a watchOS part into the same project as a standalone app. When I integrate HealthKit into the watchOS part analogous to my iOS, I get an error message in Xcode that the info.plist needs to be adjusted accordingly for the HealthKit rights.

I get following error for the HealthKit watchOS integration:

[image: error message in watchOS integration]

I already tried to set up a second PropertyList in the watchOS part, which unfortunately was not successful.

How do I have to set up the permissions for HealthKit for the watchOS? Can the info.plist from the iOS part be provided directly to both project parts?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for my problem: [Apple Release Notes for Xcode 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes)

"Projects created from several templates no longer require configuration files such as entitlements and Info.plist files. Configure common fields in the target’s Info tab, and build settings in the project editor. These files are added to the project when additional fields are used. (68254857)"